# Unable to fetch products for sale from App Store

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying to add functionality inapp purchases in my app. I'm using the in_app_purchase 0.2.1 package. I follow all the steps to create products in the App Store, then add them to the app.
In my code i trying to fetch products by id but aways I receve empty list. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpQKL.jpg

//Here connection isAvailable = true

```
Future<void> initStoreInfo() async {
    final bool isAvailable = await _connection.isAvailable();
    print(isAvailable);
    if (!isAvailable) {
      setState(() {
        _isAvailable = isAvailable;
        _products = [];
        _purchases = [];
        _loading = false;
      });
}
```

//Here products is Empty

```
Future<Null> getProducts() async {
    const Set<String> _kIds = {
      'com.myproductId1',
      'com.myproductId2',
      'com.myproductId3',
    };
    final ProductDetailsResponse response =
        await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.queryProductDetails(_kIds);
    if (!response.notFoundIDs.isEmpty) {
      print('Not Found');
      // Handle the error.
    }
    List<ProductDetails> products = response.productDetails;
    print(products);
  }
```

Comment: I hope you happy. Do you complete the Agreements, tax, and banking overview section? If you don't complete this section, App Store doesn't send product details. And you can find more detail from (https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/) under "Preparing" when you complete this section can get in-app purchase products and detail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My status in Agreements, tax, and banking is Pending User Information.I will complete this section and will try again.